# I want to search all the person in city by giving the city name

Tags: java, sql

My code is:

```
if(searchby.equals("City"))
{
  try
  {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    System.out.println("\n Driver loaded");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name FROM FAMILYcensus WHERE Name.City LIKE='" + tfsearch.getText() + "'");
    System.out.println("Hi");

    rs.next();
    String city = rs.getString("NAME");
    System.out.println("NAME: " + city );

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RECORD FOUND");
    tasearch.setText(city);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION " + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: The piece of the code commented is not part of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

there is no such operator as `like = 'boston'` in sql.
its either `city = 'boston'` or `city like 'boston'` where the second will tolerate differences, depending on how the database is configured.